# How to filter a 2 level list based on values within sublists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter

Think that the following list is a table, where sublist[0] contains the column headers.

```
data = [
            ['S1', 'S2 ', 'ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], 
            ['X' ,  'X' , 'GRT'    ,  1,    4  ], 
            [''  ,  'X' , 'OIP'    ,  3,    2  ], 
            [''  ,  'X' , 'LKJ'    ,  2,    7  ], 
            ['X' ,  ''  , 'UBC'    ,  1,    0  ]
        ]
```

I'm trying to filter the list based on the values in "column S1" and "column S2".

I want to get:

- a new list "S1" containing the sublists that has an "X" in "column S1"
- a new list "S2" containing the sublists that has an "X" in "column S2"

Like this:

```
S1 = [
            ['ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], 
            ['GRT',      1,    4  ], 
            ['UBC',      1,    0  ]
        ]       

S2 = [
            ['ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], 
            ['GRT',      1,    4  ], 
            ['OIP',      3,    2  ], 
            ['LKJ',      2,    7  ]
        ]
```

Below I show the code I have so far, where I make a copy of source list `data` an then check which sublist doesn't have "X" in "column S1". I get correct content in new list `S1`,
but I don't know why the source list `data` is being modified and I cannot use it to get new list `S2`.

```py
S1 = data
for sublist in S1[1:]:
    if sublist[0] != "X":
            s1.remove(sublist)

s2 = data
for sublist in S2[1:]:
    if sublist[1] != "X":
            s2.remove(sublist)


>>> data
[['S1', 'S2 ', 'ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], ['X', 'X', 'GRT', 1, 4], ['X', '', 'UBC', 1, 0]]
>>> S1
[['S1', 'S2 ', 'ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], ['X', 'X', 'GRT', 1, 4], ['X', '', 'UBC', 1, 0]]
>>>
```

How would be a better way to get lists `S1` and `S2`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because simply assigning the list to a new name does not make a copy.

You might be able to make your solution work by doing

```
S1 = data[:]  # slicing makes a copy
S2 = data[:]
```

instead.

---

Here's a generic solution:

```
def split_from_columns(ls, i_columns=(), indicator='X'):
    for i in i_columns:
        yield [
            [v for k, v in enumerate(sl) if k not in i_columns]
            for j, sl in enumerate(ls)
            if j == 0 or sl[i] == indicator
        ]
```

Usage:

```
>>> S1, S2 = split_from_columns(data, i_columns=(0, 1))
>>> S1
[['ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], ['GRT', 1, 4], ['UBC', 1, 0]]
>>> S2
[['ELEMENT', 'C1', 'C2'], ['GRT', 1, 4], ['OIP', 3, 2], ['LKJ', 2, 7]]
```

The `if j == 0` part makes sure we always copy the header. You can change `i_columns` to adjust where the indicator columns are.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help. It work pretty fine. I'm new to python, I'm trying to understand your code. In actual list, there are "columns" from S1 to S4 and these discriminating columns are from column 3 to column 6. How to adapt your code to be able to take discriminating columns in specific positions (for example column 3rd to 6th)?

Comment: @GerCas Works with arbitrary discriminating column positions now.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for your help and time. It works pretty fine.